# Error in downloading flask package in python using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install `flask` in `python3`. On giving the command `python -m pip install flask`, I get the error

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/flask/   Retrying (Retry(total=3,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/flask/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
>   after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/flask/   Retrying (Retry(total=1,
>   connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection
>   broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>   certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/flask/   Retrying
>   (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
>   after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:748)'),)': /simple/flask/   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/flask/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate
>   verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),)) - skipping   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for flask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to install python packages \[SSL: TLSV1\_ALERT\_PROTOCOL\_VERSION\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768770/not-able-to-install-python-packages-ssl-tlsv1-alert-protocol-version)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working solution:

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip
```

You can install any pkg replacing "--upgrade pip".

For the permenant solution, you need to edit pip.ini file and add following:

```
[global]
trusted-host=
    pypi.python.org
    pypi.org
    files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: I don't see pip.ini in site-packages directory. can you tell where it is located?

Comment: Try running "pip config -vvv list"